# Proof by induction that $\frac13(n^3-n)$ is an integer. Am I on the correct path?

Tags: proof-verification, induction

I have been trying to prove $$\frac{n^3-n}{3}=k\in \mathbb N $$
I have tried the following calculations, have however difficulties in the final step.

Could you help me out?

Here are my calculations:

[image]

Comment: Yeah I know, I forgot the induction hypothesis, but I just left it out, as those are just some exercises for myself, nothing I need to hand in...

Comment: Since $n^2$ and $n$ are naturals, and naturals are closed under addition, we have the conclusion right?

Answer (score 4):

I suspect the $k$ in $k \in \mathbb N$ is confusing you

You have shown that $\dfrac{(n+1)^3-(n+1)}{3}=\dfrac{n^3-n}{3} +n^2+n$ and you know that

- $\dfrac{n^3-n}{3}$ is an element of $\mathbb N$ (by hypothesis)
- $n^2+n$ is an element of $\mathbb N$ (multiplication and addition of integers)
- $\dfrac{n^3-n}{3} +n^2+n$ is an element of $\mathbb N$ (addition of integers)

so $\dfrac{(n+1)^3-(n+1)}{3}$ is an element of $\mathbb N$, *quod erat demonstrandum*

Comment: Thank you. But do I not need to transform everything in a way such that the original statement is visible again? ( I do not know how, but in another formula I transformed it such that I had the original statement, with all n's changed to n+1....)

Comment: @thebilly You want to show $\frac{n^3-n}{3}\in \mathbb N$ by induction.  You proved it for $n=2$.  I would say that the next step should be something like "if it is true for $n=m$ then it is true for $n=m+1$ because $\frac{(m+1)^3-(m+1)}{3}=\frac{m^3-m}{3} +m^2+m$ which is a positive integer".  Finally you say the hypothesis is true for all integer $n\ge 2$ *by induction*. And you are done

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Note that

$$\frac{n^3-n}{3} = \frac{n(n^2-1)}{3} = \frac{n(n+1)(n-1)}{3}$$

From here, you have a product of three consecutive integers in the numerator. What can you conclude from that?

Comment: that the product of those integers is an integer as well?

Comment: Any three consecutive integers must include a multiple of $3$, so their product must also be a multiple of $3$. (At the time I typed this, I didn’t see the **induction** part, so you can just keep this in mind as an alternative approach perhaps.)

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

$\frac {n^3-n}3+n^2+n=\frac {n^3+3n^2+3n-n}3=\frac {n^3+3n^2+3n+1-n-1}3=\frac {(n+1)^3-(n+1)}3$

Answer (score 1):

Hypothesis : $3|(n^3-n)$.

Step $n+1$:

$(n+1)^3 -(n+1)=$

$(n^3 +3n^3+3n+1) -n -1=$

$(n^3-n)+ 3(n^3+n)$ ;

The second term is divisible by 3, so is the first term  by hypothesis.

Comment: Ah right. Thank you.

Comment: thebilly.Welcome:)

Answer (score 0):

For the induction, you, in fact, reach your goal since $\frac{n^3-n}{3}$ is an integer by the inductive hypothesis.

If you do not to prove it with induction, there are other ways to do so.

- Consider Fermat Little Theorem. This theorem says that $n^p-n$ is always divisible by $p$ where $p$ is a prime. You just reach your goal in one step!
- You may also notice that $n^3-n = n(n^2-1) = (n-1)n(n+1)$. Now, one of these three consecutive integers must be divisible by $3$. This also follows from a theorem saying that, any $k$ consecutive integers is divisible by $k!$. According to this theorem, this number is divisible by $6$ too!

Comment: Thank you. I'll remember the second bullet point. This comes up a lot in my exercises...